# Security for a web app through Active Directory

Tags: security, active-directory

Here is a situation I am currently addressing. I am working on a Web project with its security being tied up with the Active Directory. Which means technically when you add a user through the application we are adding a new user to the Active Directory on the Server. Now my question is, is this a good practise?

At this point I think of a vulnerabilty which is you could do a remote desktop on to the deployment server with the account you created through the Application (Please correct me if I am wrong). But I just want to confirm this before I could inform this to my Architect.

Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated.

Awaiting your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the web application has permission to create accounts in Active Directory, then this means that the web application presumably has an account with (possibly limited) administrative rights to the Active Directory domain.  That could potentially be used for all sorts of bad things if you're not careful.

If you're going to proceed, then the first step, if you haven't already done so, is to delegate administrative rights to your web application's account so that it can only create accounts within a particular OU.  See [this article](http://www.topbits.com/how-to-delegate-administrator-privileges-in-active-directory.html) for details, or search Google for other descriptions.

You'll probably also want to set up Group Policy and group memberships to further restrict the newly created accounts (for example, disabling Remote Desktop), and you'll want to do so in a way that doesn't rely on the web application doing the right thing (as an extra layer of security in case the web application is compromised).

[ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to find out about Active Directory's security model and how to best set up these various restrictions.

Finally, if you don't *need* to have users automatically created within your Active Directory domain, then you should consider other approaches.  If you're only looking to use Active Directory as a stable, robust source of user authentication, for example, then you can use [Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory#ADAM.2FAD_LDS) (formerly known as Active Directory Application Mode) to get Active Directory's functionality without any affect on your domain's security.